# Transparent background for input type="image"

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to add an image (being used as a button) of a magnifying glass that has a transparent background but when added to my site it shows with a white background. I tried to do background: transparent and background-color: transparent but neither worked. Here's my code:

```css
.observe {
  position: absolute;
  right: -50px;
  width: 25px;
}
```

```html
<input type="image" className="observe" src="https://www.pinclipart.com/picdir/middle/523-5232872_magnifying-glass-clipart.png"></input>
```

Comment: "magnifying_glass.png" does this have a transparent background?

Comment: @RavishaHesh yes it does

Comment: Can you put up a working example so we can see for ourselves. see [link]https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @AHaworth I think that should be good. Sorry this is my first time posting on stackoverflow

Comment: The icon does not have a transparent background.

Comment: @Engin I just tested with 5 other images with a transparent background and same thing.

Comment: When I try with another icon, it works fine. By the way an input does not require a closing tag. Try this `<input type="image" className="observe" src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/512/1076/1076744.png" />`

Comment: Maybe your problem could be that you are using the `<input>` element. They are always a little pesky due to different browsers interacting with them a bit differently from one another. I would suggest that you have a `<span>` element and set the image as a `background-image` property to that span element.

Comment: Please note that the ```ìnput``` tag doesn't have a closing tag.

Comment: Your png is not transparent, it sort of pretends to be by having hatching. You need to find a png with real transparency.

Answer (score 0):

Please download the proper png file with transparent background and try again, there is nothing wrong with your code your png is not transparent.

Try with this png file:
https://pngtree.com/freepng/a-magnifying-glass_3094794.html

download and try!